# Magento2 widget atomic type

Tags: magento2, widget

I want create a widget.xml like that:

```
<parameter name="attribute_options" xsi:type="MT\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Attribute\Option"  visible="true">
            <label translate="true">Attribute Options</label>
            <description translate="true">Select attribute options to show</description>
        </parameter>
```

So, could I create a new parameter type like xsi:type="MT\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Attribute\Option" ? If no, how can expand new atomic type?

Answer (score 0):

You can't create new atomic types. In the XML schema definition file:  /vendor/magento/module-widget/etc/widget.xsd are defined all allowed types.

For you case I guess that you want to add parameter with type select and populate with custom options. Then you should set attribute xsi:type to "select" and another "source_model" attribute with value MT\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Attribute\Option like this:

```
<parameter name="attribute_options" xsi:type="select" source_model="MT\Widget\Block\Adminhtml\Widget\Attribute\Option" visible="true">
    <label translate="true">Attribute Options</label>
    <description translate="true">Select attribute options to show</description>
</parameter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define block type and then insert block like this:

```
<parameter name="id_path" xsi:type="block" visible="true" required="true" sort_order="10">
    <label translate="true">Product</label>
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Widget\Chooser">
        <data>
            <item name="button" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="open" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Select Product...</item>
            </item>
        </data>
    </block>
</parameter>
```

Check file app/code/Magento/Catalog/etc/widget.xml for example code.